# Hashem's Gratitude on Yom Kippur

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, midrash, yom-kippur

Rav Aharon Kotler z"tl apparently would often say a Chazal during Yomim Noraim about Hashem having gratitude for us doing teshuva on Yom Kippur. Just like a king having a grand meal which he is afraid no one will attend, Hashem has gratitude that we utilize the special day of Yom Kippur.

Where is this Chazal?

Answer (score 2):

Is it the Yalkut Shimoni, Tehilim 25 (remez 702 'ז) [Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.702.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)?